# how to add proxy to s3 so i can consume service hosted in EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, rest, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to aws, I have hosted all UI in s3 bucket and used cloudfont too. Now i have hosted all the restApi in EC2 instance.

angular UI -> s3 bucket (example.com)
backend SpringBoot restApi -> EC2 instance (api.exaple.com)

But can someone tell how to consume the API calls hosted in EC2 (api.example.com) from S3 (example.com) bucket/ cloud front.

I have hosted sprint boot rest api in EC2 instance (api.example.com:8080).

1. s3 bucket says method not allowed for (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) methods.
2. For the above reason i hard coded the api.example.com in the code, so all my requests will redirect to api.example.com -> here the issue is browser will not allow cross origin.

Now i want to know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [enable CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) on your S3 bucket.

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) defines a way for client web
>   applications that are loaded in one domain to interact with resources
>   in a different domain. With CORS support, you can build rich
>   client-side web applications with Amazon S3 and selectively allow
>   cross-origin access to your Amazon S3 resources.

Comment: i am adding CORS configuration in s3 properties like below 
`<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://api.example.com:8081</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>`

Comment: Make sure both your S3 static files and REST API are using the same mode - either http or https. You'll likely have trouble calling REST http endpoint from https web page.

Comment: Issue was i did not add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)` at rest controller. now its working as expected. Thank you for the quick response @Anton